# Is internet connection needed to run an access point on laptop?

Tags: networking

I want to connect to raspberry pi to a laptop.

The idea is to connect it to the laptop without using router or Ethernet cable so I want to make an access point from laptop and connect the pi to it with wifi dongle. We can communicate through ssh.

Do I need an internet connection to make access point?

Will any device connected get an IP address or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your raspberry pi into a access point and connect to it but you need a [wifi adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/products/814) capable of doing that.

To set it up you need to first connect to it via ethernet and install hostapd isc-dhcp-server. Make sure you have first expanded the file system and updated the Raspberry. If you use Raspbian you can use [raspi-config](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md).

When all that is done you need to set up DHCP server:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Find the lines that say

```
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
```

and change them to add a # in the beginning so they say

```
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
```

Find the lines that say

```
# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
#authoritative;
```

and remove the # so it says

```
# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;
```

Then scroll down to the bottom and add the following lines

```
subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
    option routers 192.168.42.1;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Save the file by typing in Control-X then Y then return

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

and scroll down to INTERFACES="" and update it to say INTERFACES="wlan0"

close and save the file

## Set up wlan0 for static IP

If you happen to have wlan0 active because you set it up, run sudo ifdown wlan0
There's no harm in running it if you're not sure

Next we will set up the wlan0 connection to be static and incoming. run:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Find the line `auto wlan0` and add a `#` in front of the line, and in front of every line afterwards. If you don't have that line, just make sure it looks like the screenshot below in the end! Basically just remove any old wlan0 configuration settings, we'll be changing them up

Depending on your existing setup/distribution there might be more or less text and it may vary a little bit

Add the lines

```
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After allow-hotplug wlan0 - see below for an example of what it should look like.  Any other lines afterwards should have a # in front to disable them

Save the file (Control-X Y and hit return)

Assign a static IP address to the wifi adapter by running

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.42.1
```

## Configure Access Point

Now we can configure the access point details. We will set up a password-protected network so only people with the password can connect.

Create a new file by running

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Paste the following in, you can change the text after ssid= to another name, that will be the network broadcast name. The password can be changed with the text after wpa_passphrase=

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=Pi_AP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=Raspberry
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

If you are not using the Adafruit wifi adapters, you may have to change the driver=rtl871xdrv to say driver=nl80211 or something, we don't have tutorial support for that tho, YMMV!

Save as usual. Make sure each line has no extra spaces or tabs at the end or beginning - this file is pretty picky!

Now we will tell the Pi where to find this configuration file. Run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd
```

Find the line #DAEMON_CONF="" and edit it so it says DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
Don't forget to remove the # in front to activate it!

Then save the file

## Configure Network Address Translation

Setting up NAT will allow multiple clients to connect to the WiFi and have all the data 'tunneled' through the single Ethernet IP. (But you should do it even if only one client is going to connect)

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Scroll to the bottom and add

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

on a new line. Save the file. This will start IP forwarding on boot up

Also run

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

to activate it immediately

Run the following commands to create the network translation between the ethernet port eth0 and the wifi port wlan0

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

You can check to see whats in the tables with

```
sudo iptables -t nat -S
sudo iptables -S
```

To make this happen on reboot (so you don't have to type it every time) run

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add

```
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

to the very end

## Update hostapd

Before we can run the access point software, we have to update it to a version that supports the WiFi adapter. 
First get the new version by typing in

```
wget http://adafruit-download.s3.amazonaws.com/adafruit_hostapd_14128.zip
```

to download the new version (check the next section for how to compile your own updated hostapd) then

```
unzip adafruit_hostapd_14128.zip
```

to uncompress it. Move the old version out of the way with

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd.ORIG
```

And move the new version back with

```
sudo mv hostapd /usr/sbin
```

set it up so its valid to run with

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/hostapd
```

## Test the access point host!

Run

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

To manually run hostapd with our configuration file. You should see it set up and use wlan0 then you can check with another wifi computer that you see your SSID show up. If so, you have successfully set up the access point.

if everything is setup correctly run

```
sudo service hostapd start 
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

you can always check the status of the host AP server and the DHCP server with

```
sudo service hostapd status
sudo service isc-dhcp-server status
```

To start the daemon services. Verify that they both start successfully (no 'failure' or 'errors')
Then to make it so it runs every time on boot

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable 
sudo update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server enable
```

So it is technically possible, but it is much easier to just use a ethernet cable or an existing access point.

[Here is a pdf with images](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf)